# Why did Tvastar, the father of Vritra fashion the Vajra that killed his own son?

Tags: rig-veda, indra, vedic-gods, shatapatha-brahmana, tvashtar

The Shatpatha Brahmana states that Vritra was created by Tvastar to avenge the killing of Trisiras by Indra. However, many verses in RV call Tvastar the creator of Vajra for example [Rigved 1.32.1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01032.htm) says:

> 1 I WILL declare the manly deeds of Indra, the first that he achieved, the Thunder-wielder.
>   He slew the Dragon, then disclosed the waters, and cleft the channels of the mountain torrents.
>   2 He slew the Dragon lying on the mountain: **his heavenly bolt of thunder Tvaṣṭar fashioned.**
>   Like lowing kine in rapid flow descending the waters glided downward to the ocean.

**My question is, why did Tvastar, create the only weapon that could destroy his own son?**

Comment: Rig veda book 1 hymn 84 verse 13 also  mentions rishi dadhichi preprared thunder bolt and purans and mahabharat also agre this,you can see in sacred texts.i am new here I don't know how to copy and paste link here.

Comment: @karmanya Dadhichi gave his bones for the Vajra but it was Tvashtar who fashioned it

Comment: But why indra had killed trisiras?

Comment: @aniketkumarsingh because he was being a sort of a double agent for the Asuras. Check this question for details - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/who-is-the-wood-cutter-indra-promised-would-be-honored-in-every-yagna

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason Lord Tvastar created vajra for Indra is discribed  [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv02.htm)  in tattireya samhita of yajur veda kanda 2.

4.12

> Tvastr, his son slain, offered Soma excluding Indra. Indra desired an invitation to the rite, but he did not invite him, (saying), 'Thou hast slain my son.' He made a disturbance of the sacrifice, and forcibly drank the Soma. The remains of it Tvastr cast upon the Ahavaniya (fire), saying, 'Hail! wax great, Indra's foe. While (the fire) was flaming upwards to strike, just then of itself it stayed; whether so much was before [1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv02.htm), or so much was over the fire, be sprang up alive and came into union with Agni and Soma. He grew on all sides an arrow(shot), he enveloped these worlds. Because he enveloped these worlds, therefore is Vrtra, Vrtra. **Indra feared him, and Tvastr too;  Tvastr dipped his bolt for him;t**he bolt was fervour; he could not restrain it.

This hymn discribes Onces Tvastar deva  offered soma to devas but he excluded Indra deva cause he had slain his son Visvarupa,But still Indra entered the sacrifice and drank the soma and then Tvastar created vritra but he became so strong that  not only Indra his father Tvastar even become afraid of him!so he created Thunderbolt For Indra deva to kill Vritra.

Comment: Thank you Karmanya yes it certainly seems plausible. Tvashtar created a monster to avenge his son's death but realized that he did not know how to control it hence created the means to its destruction as well.

Comment: @Dr. Vineet Aggarwal yeah you are right,I was reading tattireya samhita and I found this answer.I only use to think that only brahmanas mention Indra killing of vishvarupa but Veda samhitas also mention this!